# Home-like user interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, homescreen

I would like to add a user interface similar to the iPhone homescreen to my app. Is there an open source project which deals with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Three20](http://three20.info/) Framework used in Facebook uses one ([LauncherView](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher))

Comment: I looked at that but on the github page there is no reference to LauncherView anywhere, despite it being a big area of focus on the Three20.info website. Do you know where they have the code for that?